# Matlab TIme arrays and sampling

Tags: arrays, matlab, time, sample

How do I create a time array in Matlab between -10ms and 10ms with 1000 samples?  Which function do I need to use? I tried using duration function but it doesn't work

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the linspace function.  I've found this question in my triage queue but if it's reopened I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with milliseconds as the reference unit, you can simply use the [linspace function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), as follows:

```
ms = linspace(-10,10,1000);
```

or the [colon](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) construct `START:STEP:END` for vector creation:

```
samples = 1000;

v_start = -10;
v_end = 10;
v_step = (v_end - v_start) / (samples - 1);

ms = v_start:v_step:v_end;
```

You can then convert your milliseconds into any scale you want applying a proper conversion. For example:

```
msecs = linspace(-10,10,1000);
secs = msecs ./ 1000;
```